# "Playing in the field is great for fitness" which type of phrase is "in the field"?

Tags: phrases, parts-of-speech

"Playing in the field is great for fitness" here, is "in the field" an adjective phrase or an adverbial phrase?

I am rooting for "adverbial phrase" since the expression tells us about where "playing" took place but I am just not sure. Could anyone help?

Comment: What do you mean by: Playing in the field?? in the field is a prepositional phrase **used as an adverb**.

Answer (score 1):

It is a prepositional phrase functioning as an adverb. As you stated, it modifies the verb "playing."

Comment: Then, in exams should I answer "prepositional phrase" or "adverbial phrase " or will both be equally correct?

Comment: In exams you should do exactly what your teacher tells you to do!  If I were teaching your class, I'd call this a "prepositional phrase", and leave of the analogy to adverbs or adjectives - that kind of analogy causes more confusion, especially when applied to gerunds/participles.  However I'm not your teacher.